Determine at which points the function is analytic.
Consider the function
$$f(z)=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}-i \frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$$
I want to study where this function is differentiable, i.e. analytic.We can check where it satisfies the Cauchy Riemann equations, subject to the continuity of the partial derivatives of the real and imaginary part functions of $f$, note that
$u_{x}=\frac{\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:x}\left(x\right)\left(x^2+y^2\right)-\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:x}\left(x^2+y^2\right)x}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}=\frac{-x^2+y^2}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}$
$u_{y}=x\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:y}\left(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\right)=-x\frac{1}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2} \cdot \frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:y}\left(x^2+y^2\right)=-\frac{2xy}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}$
$v_{x}=-y\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:x}\left(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\right)=-\frac{1}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:x}\left(x^2+y^2\right)=\frac{2yx}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}$
$v_{y}=-\frac{\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:y}\left(y\right)\left(x^2+y^2\right)-\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:y}\left(x^2+y^2\right)y}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}=-\frac{x^2-y^2}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}$
Clearly $u_{x} = u_{y}$ and $u_{y} = -v_{x}$ But I don't know what happens with the continuity of the functions $u$ and $v$, any suggestions? thanks!

You’d better double-check your calculations.

@TedShifrin you are right, if the Cauchy-Riemann equations coincide, but my question is, are the functions $u$ and $v$ continuous?

Don’t you know basic continuity facts (like polynomials are continuous, product and quotient of continuous functions are continuous away from zeroes of the denominator, etc.)?

It is true, I think it is continuous in the complex plane minus the origin, which is the point where the function bursts, is it?

Right. The origin is not in the domain to start with.

I would suggest using a complex form of Cauchy-Riemann equations which narrows them down to $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}=0.$$
The reason I suggest it is the form of your function. If you consider a complex variable $z=x+iy$, then your function would take the following form:
$$
f(z) = \frac{z^*}{zz^*} = \frac{1}{z}
$$ where it is evident that the derivative is zero everywhere, hence the function is analytic.
As it comes to your calculations, I strongly suggest you check them.
